# Getting Fatal Error after updating Foogallery plugin to version 1.4.31 - running on WordPress 4.9.8

Tags: php, wordpress, updates, fatal-error, foogallery

I haven’t been updating my plugins for this site for a while: [www.12thcaulfield.asn.au](http://www.12thcaulfield.asn.au/). I saw that the WP version had recently been auto updated to 4.9.8, and that it shows as having the most recent version.

So I decided to update all my plugins also. One of which is the foogallery plugin.

After the updates, I could no longer access the dashboard or any of the backend pages under wp-admin area. I was logged in at the time of the updates, but once I logged out, I can no longer log back in.

This is the error I got when I clicked on dashboard link while logged on (after updates).. and also now that I am logged out (not able to log back in):

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_generate_password() in /websites/12/12thcaulfield.asn.au/wp-content/plugins/foogallery/includes/extensions/class-extensions-api.php on line 74.**

Here is the function inside of **class-extensions-api.php** that appears to be causing the error:

```
        /**
     * Get back the extension endpoint based on a setting
     */
    public function get_extensions_endpoint() {
        if ( 'on' === foogallery_get_setting( 'use_future_endpoint' ) ) {
            $extension_url = FOOGALLERY_EXTENSIONS_FUTURE_ENDPOINT;
        } else {
            $extension_url = FOOGALLERY_EXTENSIONS_ENDPOINT;
        }
        //make sure we always get the latest version!
        $extension_url .= '?v=' . wp_generate_password();

        return apply_filters('foogallery_extension_api_endpoint', $extension_url );
    }
```

Line 74 is where the fatal error is occuring.. which is this line in the above listed function:

```
$extension_url .= '?v=' . wp_generate_password();
```

I have gone into my files on the server, and just renamed the foogallery plugin as an experiment to see if I could allow myself to login. It worked, so now I can at least login to wp-admin, and access dashboard, etc. (Of course, none of my galleries are being displayed.. but I am hopeful they will once I solve the conflict problem).

I am hoping that once the coding error in the plugin is fixed, that I will just be able to rename the plugin, and all my previous albums and photo galleries will still be intact.

I am assuming that the newest version of the foogallery plugin isn’t compatible with the latest WP version?

Has anyone run into this same problem?  Can someone give me some guidance on how to fix the plugin?

The net results I need is to have the foogallery plugin functional (allowing me to login to wp-admin), and for all the albums and galleries I previously created to still be there.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers,
SunnyOz

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the WP 4.9.8 codebase and wp_generate_password function definately exists.

I have also been running FooGallery on the latest WP version since it was released without any issues.

What other plugins do you have installed? Have you tried disabling all other plugins except FooGallery to see if the plugin starts working? Install the [Health Check plugin](https://en-za.wordpress.org/plugins/health-check/) to disable all plugins and use the default theme (but only for your user)